# Program Doesn't Close After Quitting It In PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pygame, pyqt5

So, Recently I was trying to make an audio player using PyQt5, pygame, and mutagen. The program works pretty fine. But when I'm playing a song and try to quit the program, the program stops responding and the song continues to play. But this doesn't happen when a song is not playing, it works fine then.

Here is the Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys
import pygame as pg
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import os
import threading

pg.init()

#33206

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(425, 65, 400, 190)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon"))
        self.setWindowTitle("MultiMedia Player")

        # MenuBar
        file = QtWidgets.QAction("&Open Mp3", self)
        file.setShortcut("Ctrl + O")
        file.triggered.connect(self.open_mp3)

        # Quit
        quit = QtWidgets.QAction("&Quit", self)
        quit.setShortcut("Q")
        quit.triggered.connect(self.close_app)

        # Add Items

        items = QtWidgets.QAction("&Add Items", self)
        items.setShortcut("Ctrl + P")

        mainmenu = self.menuBar()
        filemenu = mainmenu.addMenu("&Open")
        filemenu.addAction(file)
        add_items = mainmenu.addMenu("&Add Items")
        add_items.addAction(items)
        filemenu.addAction(quit)

        self.flag = 0

        self.home()

    def home(self):

        # colors
        black = (13, 13, 13)
        light_black = (36, 36, 36)

        # Pause Button
        self.pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pause_btn.setText("Pause")
        self.pause_btn.setShortcut("p")
        self.pause_btn.move(0, 120)
        self.pause_btn.clicked.connect(self.pause)

        # Play Button
        self.play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.play_btn.setText("Play")
        self.play_btn.setShortcut("Space")
        self.play_btn.move(150, 120)
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(self.play)

        # Stop Button
        self.stop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.stop_btn.setText("Stop")
        self.stop_btn.setShortcut("s")
        self.stop_btn.move(300, 120)

        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        # color for the window

        color = QColor(70, 70, 70)

        # Volume_Up Button
        self.vup_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.vup_btn.setText("V(+)")
        self.vup_btn.setShortcut("+")
        self.vup_btn.move(300, 160)
        self.vup_btn.clicked.connect(self.volume_up)


        # Volume_Down Button
        self.vdown_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.vdown_btn.setText("V(-)")
        self.vdown_btn.setShortcut("-")
        self.vdown_btn.move(0, 160)
        self.vdown_btn.clicked.connect(self.volume_down)


        # Seek Slider

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setGeometry(20, 75, 350, 20)

        # Volume Slider

        self.v_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.v_slider.setGeometry(120, 165, 160, 20)
        self.v_slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.v_slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.v_slider.setValue(70)
        self.volume_value = self.v_slider.value()
        self.v_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_changed)
        print(self.v_slider.value() / 100)



    def msg(self, title, message):
        msg1 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg1.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon"))
        msg1.setWindowTitle(title)
        msg1.setText(message)
        msg1.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        msg1.exec_()


    def open_mp3(self):
        name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

        format = os.path.splitext(name[0])
        if format[1] == ".mp3":
            self.audio = MP3(name[0])
            self.duration = self.audio.info.length//1
            self.min = int(self.duration // 60)
            self.sec = int(self.duration % 60)

            self.total_time = str(self.min) + ":" + str(self.sec)
            print(self.total_time)

            self.slider.setMaximum(self.duration)
            self.slider.setMinimum(0)
            time = []
            time.append(self.total_time)
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.label.setText(self.total_time)
            self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 9))
            self.label.adjustSize()
            self.label.move(373, 77)

            song = name[0]
            pg.mixer.music.load(song)
            pg.mixer.music.play(1)
            pg.mixer.music.set_volume(self.v_slider.value()/100)

            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.label.setText(song)
            self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 15))
            self.label.adjustSize()
            self.label.move(0, 36)
            self.label.show()
            threading_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.cur_time).start()

        else:
            self.msg("Invalid Format", "Choose A .Mp3 File Only!")

    volume_level = pg.mixer.music.get_volume()
    print(volume_level)

    def cur_time(self):

        true = 1
        while true == 1:
            if self.flag == 0:
                self.m_time = pg.mixer.music.get_pos()
                self.mm_time = self.m_time * 0.001
                self.s_time = self.mm_time // 1
                self.slider.setValue(self.s_time)
                print(self.s_time)
                self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.seek_changed)
            if self.s_time == -1:
                self.slider.setValue(0)
                true = 2

            if self.flag == 1:
                print(self.s_time)

    def seek_changed(self):
        print(self.slider.value())
        pg.mixer.music.set_pos(self.slider.value())

    def slider_value_changed(self):
        self.volume_value = self.v_slider.value()
        pg.mixer.music.set_volume(self.v_slider.value()/100)

    def volume_up(self):
        self.volume_value = self.volume_value + 10
        self.v_slider.setValue(self.volume_value)

        if self.volume_value >= 100:
            self.volume_value = 100


        pg.mixer.music.set_volume(self.v_slider.value() / 100)
        print(self.v_slider.value() / 100)


    def volume_down(self):
        self.volume_value = self.volume_value - 10
        self.v_slider.setValue(self.volume_value)

        if self.volume_value <= 0:
            self.volume_value = 0
        pg.mixer.music.set_volume(self.v_slider.value() / 100)
        print(self.v_slider.value() / 100)


    def pause(self):
        pg.mixer.music.pause()
        self.flag = 1

    def stop(self):
        pg.mixer.music.stop()
        self.flag = -1

    def play(self):

        pg.mixer.music.unpause()
        self.flag = 0


    def close_app(self):
        choice = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self, "QUIT", "You Sure You Wanna Quit?", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass




    def items(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        song_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        widget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        widget.setDragDropMode(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

        widget.addItems([str(i) for i in range(1, 6)])
        layout.addWidget(widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're still having the `threading.Thread` running, so while the QtApplication is "closed", the program is still alive.

You should really avoid using a while loop to check for the current position, as it will call request that value each time the loop cycles, consuming a lot of unnecessary CPU resources.
Also, you're connecting the sliderMoved signal to seek_changed each time the loops cycles, which is *bad*.

Use a QTimer instead, which will update the cursor position without overloading the process:

```
    # create a timer in the window __init__
    self.cursor_updater = QtCore.QTimer(interval=100, timeout=self.cur_time)

    #...
    def cur_time(self):
        # ignore the update if the user is seeking
        if self.slider.isSliderDown():
            return
        self.slider.setValue(pg.mixer.music.get_pos() * .001)
```

Then you just need to start the timer everytime the music starts (or unpauses) and stop whenever you stop or pause.

That said, there are other issues with your code.

1. pygame and Qt run their own event loops, so you can't easily and *gracefully* quit via `sys.exit()`, nor their own `quit()` functions, as it's possible that one or both of them would just hang in their own loop without being able to actually quit, keeping the process running (looping doing almost nothing) and consuming a lot of resources. I'm no expert in using pygame *and* PyQt but, as far as I know, you can call `os._exit(0)` instead.
2. the window `closeEvent()` should be taken care of, because if the user just closes the window without quitting, there won't be any confirmation dialog and the exit procedure described above won't be called.
3. [pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_pos) "only represents how long the music has been playing; it does not take into account any starting position offsets". So you'll need to keep track of the position whenever you use `set_pos()` and compute the actual value accordingly.
4. you should really consider using layouts, or ensure that the window size is fixed, otherwise the user will be able to resize it to a size smaller than the interface is.

Comment: Never knew that my code had so many problems, thanks, I'll try to fix them all. I thought about using the layouts, just after I've written all code, was too lazy to fix it then.